# MySQL SELECT MAX slow since update MySQL 5.7.13

Tags: php, mysql

Since an update to MySQL 5.7.13 I have one query where is very slow. Givs a way to optimize it?

```
SELECT MAX(price.articlePrice) AS maxPrice
FROM articles articles 
LEFT JOIN articles_price price ON (articles.articleID=price.articleID) 
WHERE article.articleIDCategoryID = '34'
```

This search the maxPrice from 1500 DB entrys. Benchmark say 9 secons. When I try and make WHERE article.articleID = '1' it is fast. But 9 Secons for a maxPrice?

Than you for help

Comment: And did you run an explain on that? What are your current indexes what's your table structure?

Comment: if your alias name is exactly the same as your table name, why do you need it then?

Comment: Add index in your table

Comment: how many record do you have?? a million?

Comment: I don't understand the point of the OUTER join!?!?!